# Webpack-dev-server live update in Codeanywhere

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, codeanywhere

I'd love to speed up my dev / test process on Codeanywhere.

Codeanywhere's dev boxes give you some random URL to use for your host "application" (ie: index.html) like this:

`http://preview.[really-long-hash].box.codeanywhere.com/build/`

Not sure how to get from there to the webpack-dev-server if it is running. Is there a basic configuration that I'm missing?

In all the Webpack tutorials, if you're running it locally, you would access the running dev server like this :`http://localhost:8080` but `http://preview.[really-long-hash].box.codeanywhere.com:8080` just shows an error message from Codeanywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When launching the dev-server, you must configure its host IP to `0.0.0.0` using the `host` option. Then, on codeanywhere, you can access it from `http://preview.[really-long-hash].box.codeanywhere.com:8080`.

One additional note is that if your build folder is anything other than the root of the folder on which you invoke webpack-dev-server, you should also specify it using the `content-base` option.

### Example:

```
webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --host 0.0.0.0 --progress --colors --hot --content-base build
```

Note that if you get sick of typing this every time, configure an `npm` script by editing your `package.json` file and adding an entry into `scripts`, eg:

```
 "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test" : "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",

    "build" : "webpack --progress -colors",
    "dev-server" : "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --host 0.0.0.0 --progress --colors --hot --content-base build"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
```

etc...

Answer (score -1):

All web servers on codeanywhere should be set to respond to 0.0.0.0:Port (0.0.0.0:8080 in your case). You may need to configure your webapp so it doesn't point to localhost instead.

After you start your webapp, you can view your web at http://preview.[really-long-hash].box.codeanywhere.com:8080